# ¿Cómo obtengo color de la barra de títulos de Windows 10 en Java?

Tags: java, windows

¿Hay alguna función que me permita obtener el color de resaltado de la barra de títulos de una ventana cualquiera cuando está activa en Windows 10? ¿Cómo lo obtengo?

- Gracias

Answer (score 1):

La única opción que se me ocurre es un método de la clase Robot de java

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.getPixelColor(int x, int y);
```

Si lo quieres en tiempo de ejecución, la cosa sería hacer que esté maximizada la ventana si o si y luego ir probando valores, que se ubiquen por la parte de arriba de la ventana (haciendo antes click ya que quieres que la ventana esté activa según lo que dijiste)

tambien puedes hacer mover el raton a la barra de titulo de la ventana hacer click y usar el método que escribi antes para conseguir el color del pixel

Todos estos métodos los tiene implementados la clase Robot

```
robot.mouseMove(int x, int y);
robot.mousePress(int buttons);
```

te dejo el enlace al Javadoc está en el paquete java.awt (El segundo en la parte de los paquetes arriba a la izquierda):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/

Es una forma bastante mala de hacerlo, pero no se me ocurre otra forma

un saludo y gracias por leerme